# Lambda behaving differently than anonymous inner class

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-inner-class

While doing some basic lambda exercises, the output from an apparently identical anonymous inner class was giving me a different output than the lambda.

```
interface Supplier<T> {

    T get(T t);
}
```

**Scenario #1**

```
Supplier<Integer> s1 = new Supplier<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get(Integer t) {
        return t;
    }
};
Supplier<Integer> s2 = t -> t;
System.out.println(s1.get(2));
System.out.println(s2.get(2));
```

Outputs **2** and **2**. Nothing new here.

---

But when I do this:

**Scenario #2**

```
Supplier<Integer> s1 = new Supplier<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get(Integer t) {
        return t++;
    }
};
Supplier<Integer> s2 = t -> t++;
System.out.println(s1.get(2));
System.out.println(s2.get(2));
```

Outputs **2** and **3**

**QUESTION: Shouldn't both outputs be identical? Am I missing something?**

---

For the sake of completeness:
**Scenario #3**

```
Supplier<Integer> s1 = new Supplier<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get(Integer t) {
        return ++t;
    }
};
Supplier<Integer> s2 = t -> ++t;
System.out.println(s1.get(2));
System.out.println(s2.get(2));
```

Outputs **3** and **3**. Nothing new here as well.

**UPDATE: Still getting same output from 1.8.0-b132**

**UPDATE #2: Bug report:** https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8038420

**UPDATE #3: The bug has been fixed in javac, you should be able to obtain the same result now.**

Comment: I get 2 and 2 for your second snippet.

Comment: +1 for cannot replicate

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Are we looking at something related to JVM versions/builds here? I'm using build 1.8.0-ea-b81. Currently downloading a newer version. Will post updates.

Comment: I reproduce the bug on MacOS X Mavericks. Output of `java -version`: java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

Comment: I can reproduce it with `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b118)`, but not on whatever JRE8 Eclipse is using.

Comment: I can reproduce it as well.
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

Comment: Reproduced as well: 
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)`

Comment: When running under Eclipse, you are using Eclipse's compiler which doesn't have this bug -- it's not a VM problem, it's a compiler thing.

Comment: interesting: replace it to interface Supplier {int get(int t);} and it will work as expected

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to generated bytecode:

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)

**Lambda:**

```
 private static java.lang.Integer lambda$main$0(java.lang.Integer);
   descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
   Code:
     stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
        0: aload_0
        1: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
        4: iconst_1
        5: iadd
        6: invokestatic  #6                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        9: dup
       10: astore_0
       11: astore_1
       12: aload_0
       13: areturn
     LineNumberTable:
       line 20: 0
     LocalVariableTable:
       Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0      14     0     t   Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

**Anonymous class:**

```
  public java.lang.Integer get(java.lang.Integer);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=4, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: astore_2
         2: aload_1
         3: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
         6: iconst_1
         7: iadd
         8: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        11: dup
        12: astore_1
        13: astore_3
        14: aload_2
        15: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 16: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      16     0  this   LTest$1;
            0      16     1     t   Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

As you can see, in anonymous class after loading variable from local variable table (method parameter **t**) runtime store copy of parameter in another variable (**astore_2**) and then use this copy of parameter as returning value.

Lambda method doesn't make copy of parameter (load -> unbox -> add 1 -> box -> store -> load -> return).

**UPDATE**

It's definitely a javac bug.

I got source from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u

Anonymous class and lambda converts to following intermediate representations:

```
@Override()
public Integer get(Integer t) {
    return (let /*synthetic*/ final Integer $112619572 = t in 
       (let /*synthetic*/ final Integer $1295226194 = t = Integer.valueOf((int)(t.intValue() + 1)) in $112619572));
}

/*synthetic*/ private static Integer lambda$main$0(final Integer t) {
    return (let /*synthetic*/ final Integer $1146147158 = t = Integer.valueOf((int)(t.intValue() + 1)) in t);
}
```

In lambda generated method parameter marked as final, because LambdaToMethod translator 
marks all parameters as FINAL (according source code **LambdaTranslationContext.translate(…):1899**).

Then let expression builder checks variable flags and when if it’s final omits temporary variable generation
(according source code **Lower.abstractRval(…):2277**), because modification considered to be prohibited.

Possible solutions:

1. Forbid parameter modification inside lambda or
2. Remove FINAL flag from local variable (**LambdaTranslationContext.translate(…):1894**)
   and parameter (**LambdaTranslationContext.translate(…):1899**) in lamda generated method:

   ```
    case LOCAL_VAR:
      ret = new VarSymbol(FINAL, name, types.erasure(sym.type), translatedSym);
    ...

    case PARAM:
      ret = new VarSymbol(FINAL | PARAMETER, name, types.erasure(sym.type), translatedSym);
    ...
   ```

I removed FINAL flag and got expected results on tests from: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8038420

Comment: Even though there's no apparent official word on the matter yet, I'm accepting this as the correct answer. Guess I should file a bug report. Can anyone point me out on how to do that?

Comment: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/ - OpenJDK lambda-dev mailing list

Comment: Yes, that looks like a bug in javac. Fortunately, Eclipse's Java compiler doesn't have that bug.

Comment: I've posted this question on the lambda-dev list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2014-March/011983.html

Comment: I've updated my answer with copy of my message from here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2014-March/011993.html