# Java 8: Duplicate method name&signature lambda

Tags: java, java-8

I was playing around with Java 8 lambdas, method references and interface default methods to explore the wonderful world of currying, and then I got this Java error I cannot understand.

Here is the code :

```java
public class Main {

    public interface CurryBiConsumer<T, U> extends BiConsumer<T, U> {
        default public CurryConsumer<U> curryFirst(T t) {
            return (u) -> accept(t, u);
        }
        default public CurryConsumer<T> currySecond(U u) {
            return (t) -> accept(t, u);
        }
    }

    public interface CurryConsumer<T> extends Consumer<T> {
        default public Runnable curry(T t) {
            return () -> accept(t);
        }
    }

    static void execute(Runnable r) {
        System.out.println("BEFORE");
        r.run();
        System.out.println("AFTER");
    }

    static void display(String str, int count) {
        System.out.println("DISP: " + str + " " + count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CurryBiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = Main::display;

        execute(bc.curryFirst("Salomon").curry(42));
    }
}
```

Eclipse gives me no error but when I run it, I get this runtime error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:328)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:296)
    at com.test8.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file com/test8/Main$$Lambda$1
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:324)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:194)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.altMetafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:473)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:301)
    ... 2 more
```

Can someone explain What is this error, why it is happening and how to get around it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: `CurryBiConsumer` needs to be a functional interface

Comment: What version of java 8 are you using? your code compiles and runs as expected on my machine. Have you tried to run it with `java -jar` instead of through eclipse?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to extend functional interfaces, it seems not so smart to do so in my opinion.

Comment: I find extending functional interfaces to add default method very handy. They remain functional interfaces and you can add behaviour to them.
Line 34 is `CurryBiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = Main::display;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the system property `jdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses` to point to a directory on your filesystem. You'll get the bytecode of the synthesized anonymous class `com/test8/Main$$Lambda$1` dumped to that location. Open that class file with `javap` to see what has happened. You should find two declarations of the same method there.

#### Update

This is the `javap` output produced by the above procedure, when compiled with Eclipse:

```
final class test.Main$$Lambda$1 implements test.Main$CurryBiConsumer {
  public void accept(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_1       
       1: checkcast     #14                 // class java/lang/String
       4: aload_2       
       5: checkcast     #16                 // class java/lang/Integer
       8: invokestatic  #22                 // Method test/Main.lambda$0:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
      11: return        

  public void accept(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_1       
       1: checkcast     #14                 // class java/lang/String
       4: aload_2       
       5: checkcast     #16                 // class java/lang/Integer
       8: invokestatic  #22                 // Method test/Main.lambda$0:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
      11: return        
}
```

And this is how it should be, and what `javac` does:

```
final class test.Main$$Lambda$1 implements test.Main$CurryBiConsumer {
  public void accept(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_1       
       1: checkcast     #14                 // class java/lang/String
       4: aload_2       
       5: checkcast     #16                 // class java/lang/Integer
       8: invokevirtual #20                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
      11: invokestatic  #26                 // Method test/Main.display:(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      14: return        
}
```

Conclusion: this is an issue with the Eclipse JDT compiler. Someone should report it :)

### Update

As of Eclipse Luna this bug has been fixed.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: In Eclipse, yes; with javac, no. It's an Eclipse bug.

Comment: Apropos Java 8 bugs, have you followed this question yesterday, where it turns out that `javac` compiles `(i) -> i++` into `(i) -> i+1`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648079/lambda-behaving-differently-than-anonymous-inner-class

Comment: Too late to report it, I have Luna and it doesn't reproduce there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the JRE Runtime installed in eclipse solved the issue