# Type inference limitations with lambda expressions

Tags: java, java-8, type-inference, lambda

While Java 8's type inference seems much improved, I've hit on a possible limitation and I'm not sure if there's some workaround I'm missing. The scenario:

```
class Foo<T> {
  <U> void apply(Function<T, Consumer<U>> bar) {}
}

class Bar {
  void setBar(String bar){}
}

Foo<Bar> foo = new Foo<>();
```

This works:

```
foo.<String>apply(bar -> bar::setBar);
```

This does not:

```
foo.apply(bar -> bar::setBar);
```

Is there any way to get type inference to work in this sort of situation?

Comment: It's most certainly a bug rather than a limitation, because compiler does know everything it needs in both cases. 
But given Java history, I guess it will stay not fixed until Java 9 (in 5-10 years)

Comment: I don't know if it's technically a bug - I had a hard time telling from the JLS if it should infer in this case or not. I'd love to know if there's something else I can do to workaround though.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Because it doesn't compile in Eclipse but does with javac for me.

Comment: @ZouZou Great observation - I am using Eclipse! Very happy to know it works via JavaC, though publishing an API that Eclipse users can't use is a bummer. Guess I'll have to nag the Eclipse folks to fix things.

Comment: For the workarounds — you can use Scala, it compiles similar code just fine: http://ideone.com/8GuI6n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an eclipse bug. Both compile fine with Netbeans or javac.

It seems that Eclipse has [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23837957/829571) a few [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22686985/829571) with java 8...

Comment: Lesson learned - If eclipse is being weird, always test with javac.

Comment: @JoshStone ... and vice versa. There are cases where it's just the other way around...